# DirectX 9 refuses to install

Tags: installation, directx, virtual-machine, directx-9

I'm trying to install DirectX 9 on a Win7 x64 VM (due to a long story I won't get into) but the installer goes from the EULA directly to the Installation Complete portion, but does not say it found a newer version of DirectX or that the installation failed. Is there any way to either force it to install or extract the DLLs from the offline installer?
EDIT: The installer does not generate a log file or show up in the Installed Programs list afterward.

Comment: Windows 7 already comes with DirectX 9. What Installer are you trying to run? Use the Web Updater (that asks to install the Bing Toolbar) to install any missing versioned DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running the wrong installer or something. The [2010 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109) package seems to support windows 7. If you know exactly what DLLs you need, you can unzip the installers and the many cab files inside with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or other tools

Also don't forget that many of these installers merely *extract* files, and there's a second installer that should (but sometimes dosen't) automatically run

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't install "DirectX" on Windows 7. It comes with DirectX 9.0c, DirectX 10, and DirectX 11 already. The *DirectX End-User Runtime* therefore never installs "DirectX" on any version of Windows newer than Windows XP Service Pack 2.

It does, however, still install some of the optional (and largely deprecated) utility bits like D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, etc. See [KB79113](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179113/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx) under the section "List of file failures that the DirectX End-User Runtime package fixes".

The DirectX End-User Runtime does create a log file. See `%WINDIR%\Logs` for the file `DirectX.log`.

See [Not So Direct Setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)

Comment: The only way to update the version of DirectX on Windows is to install a Service Pack, a KB update, or upgrade to a new version of Windows. For Windows 7 Service Pack 1, you can install DirectX 11.1 using [2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670838) which does a [partial update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx) to the Windows 8 version. There are no newer versions of DirectX available for Windows 7. You also cannot 'downgrade' the version of DirectX.